# outer measure is invariant with translation

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

> Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Define $A+c$ to be the set
> $$
> A+c=\{x+c \mid x \in A\}
> $$
> a) Prove $m^{*}(A+c)=m^{*}(A)$.
> b) Prove that $A+c$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

a) We know that, $$
m^{*}(A)=\inf \left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(I_{k}\right):\left(I_{k}\right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \text { is a sequence of open intervals with } A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}\right\}
$$

Here, $A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}$ then $A+c \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}+c$

And we know that, $\ell\left(I_{k}\right)=\ell\left(I_{k}+c\right)$ then $m^*(A+c)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(I_{k}+c\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(I_{k}\right)=m^*(A)$

b) A set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is Lebesgue measurable if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an open set $G$ so that $E \subseteq G$ and
$$
m^{*}(G \backslash E)<\epsilon \text {. }
$$

$(\Longleftarrow)$ Hence, for any $\epsilon>0\:\exists G_{\epsilon}:A\subset G_{\epsilon}\: \land \: m^*(G_{\epsilon}\setminus A)<\epsilon $

Now, $A\subset G_{\epsilon} \stackrel{?}{\implies} A+c\subset G_{\epsilon}+c$ and $\ell(A+c)=\ell(A),\: \ell(G_{\epsilon}+c)=\ell(G_{\epsilon})$

Then can I say $$m^*((G_{\epsilon}+c)\setminus (A+c)) \stackrel{?}{=} m^*(G_{\epsilon}\setminus A)<\epsilon$$

$(\implies)$ We just need to take $-c$ and argue the same thing.

It will be a great help if anyone verify my proof. And suggest me any kind of improvement.

Comment: The last statement before (b) is incorrect. You cannot drop the $\inf$ like that.

Comment: Type mistake. Can I say $m^*(A+c)=\inf\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(I_{k}+c\right)\stackrel{?}{=}\inf\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(I_{k}\right)=m^*(A)$? @copper.hat

Comment: Is there any other mistake in my proof? @copper.hat Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I would write
\begin{eqnarray}
m^{*}(A) &=& \inf \left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(I_{k}\right) \mid I_{k}\text { open intervals, } A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}\right\} \\
&=& \inf \left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(I_{k} +c\right) \mid I_{k}\text { open intervals, } A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}\right\} \\
&=& \inf \left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(I_{k} +c\right) \mid I_{k}+c\text { open intervals, } A+c \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}+c\right\} \\
&=& \inf \left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(J_{k}\right) \mid J_{k}\text { open intervals, } A+c \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} J_{k}\right\} \\
&=& m^*(A+c)
\end{eqnarray}

For Part (b) I would note that
$(U \setminus A) +c = (U +c) \setminus (A +c)$, so
$m^* (U \setminus A) < \epsilon$ **iff** $m^*((U +c) \setminus (A +c) ) < \epsilon$.